# Spring Cloud Client Config alternate profile if configserver fails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-cloud

How to set active profile to be local if configserver fails?.
Currently I am using spring boot version:2.7.12 and cloud-dependencies 2022.0.8